# How can I update the User record with a trigger being fired by a portal user?

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing

The requirement is basically to run a query to update a number on a user custom field. The problem is that this code is being run on a trigger which has the  `after insert` and `after update` events and the `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` error is being thrown.

I already tried using `without sharing` on the class (which is a trigger handler).

Comment: Did you enable access to that custom field for portal user?

Comment: You could move to something async, where there are several options which allow you to specify the context user.

Comment: @kurunve The portal user shouldn't have access to the user object, I believe. But I think that's worth a try.

Comment: @AdrianLarson could you please provide on how to specify the context user on async calls?

Comment: Well you can log in as someone else to schedule jobs, so that part's easy. Platform Event subscriber triggers also would probably work here if you want to go down that road.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be that you move to a scheduled rollup calculation. You can then impersonate whatever user you wish to schedule the job, preferably some sort of generic admin user. That way, the rollup will always be calculated by someone who should have all the appropriate permissions.

If you want it sooner, then you could try `Platform Events`. Here you might configure a long text field which contains newline delimited Id values (creatively named `Ids__c`), and then have a subscriber trigger calculate the rollups. This approach seems to have a similar time scale as `@future` invocations in my experience so far.

From your current trigger, your publish logic would look something like:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
// populate somehow
EventBus.publish(new MyEvent__e(
    Ids__c = String.join(new List<Id>(ids), '\n')
    //, any other state you need to save
));
```

Then your subscriber logic would look something like:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for (MyEvent__e event : events)
    ids.addAll((List<Id>)event.Ids__c.split('\n'));

List<User> records = [
    SELECT (SELECT Id FROM SomeChildren__r)
    FROM User WHERE Id IN :ids
];
// calculate rollups
update records;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that scheduled rollup isn't an option, because I really need this information right after the custom object's trigger is run. "Right after" might not be the proper expression, but it really is a short time (enough to make a scheduled process inviable, unless what you meant was to schedule the process to run after the trigger runs).